# Localization using .resx files working on LocalHost but not server MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, embedded-resource

I have setup localisation and debugged it completely fine on IIS Express on my local machine. I have uploaded the compiled resource .dll files located in the `/bin/LANG_CODE` folders to my server and edited the Web.Config.

I added this to the module tags:
`<add name="LangQueryAppenderModule" type="Central.HttpModules.LangQueryAppenderModule" />`

And I added this to the `system.web` tags in the Web.Config: `<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />`

The behaviour on the localmachine is the complete desired result in that when I type `localhost:port/controller` it will redirect me to `localhost:port/en/controller` and if I change the language code to `fr` it will display the correct string values for the French version of my website.

On my published version of the site `http://example.com/controller` it will correctly redirect to me `http://example.com/en/controller` but when I change the language code to any of the supported it will still display the English string values rather than displaying the desired language like my local machine does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with Visual Studio 2015's FTP publishing service. For some reason the .dll resource files were not uploading when I clicked on the folders to upload, even though the UI says otherwise. I had to expand the folders where the resource.dll files were located and individually click and upload for them to be successfully uploaded to my server.

The joys of being a programmer!